# Why does this static bool not need to be initialized?

Tags: c#, initialization, boolean

if you call checkBool, it will always return "why does this not fail"

Why is this and why do you not need to initialize _bool?

```
public sealed class falsefalse
{
    private static bool _bool;
    public static string checkBool()
    {
        if (!_bool)
            return "why does this not fail";
        else return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a difference between fields (class-level variables) and local variables (variable declared inside a method (accessor etc.) body) in C#. Fields are automatically initialized to the default value of the type. Local variables must be definitely assigned to (explicitly initalized) before they can be read.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fields of class have their [default values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691171%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) if you don't initialize them explicitly. Default value for type `bool` is `false`. See C# specification [10.4.4 Field initialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645756%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

> The initial value of a field, whether it be a static field or an
>   instance field, is the default value (Section 5.2) of the field's
>   type.

Take a look at [Default Values Table (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83fhsxwc.aspx)

Comment: Thank you, I knew about default values, but didn't know that fields of a class would automatically use default values.

Comment: For fields of a `struct`, with static fields it is entirely the same. With non-static `struct` fields, you cannot initialize at the fields declaration, you must initialize in non-static constructors. There is a default struct constructor (the parameterless one) which also sets all instance fields to their default values.

Answer (score 1):

Fields are automatically initialized to their default. `default(bool)` is `false`, so in this case - unless specified otherwise - `_bool` will be initialized to `false`.